# How can I disable specific functions of a Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have received a request from a client to work with a specific plugin ([LearnPress – WordPress LMS Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/learnpress/)) and to completely disable (not simply hide) certain features on the course creation page without affecting the rest of the functionality.

In this case, course price and payment. There will be no prices but the course permissions will be managed via roles and groups (enterprise learning).

There are tutorials on plugin **installation**, **deletion**, **troubleshooting** and more, but very little information of *disabling specific options* within a plugin,
and how this would be overwritten once the plugin has been updated.

Would it be feasible to simply delete the require_once which reference to directory for the cart and price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete the 'require_once' or the plugin will not active - or you will get a fatal error. In this case (depending on the copyright, and licensing of the plugin) you will have to manually go into the plugin and alter the code.

I would suggest hiring someone to do this if you not experienced.

Comment: Thank you for that advice. I have installed XAMPP and Bitnami WordPress on Windows 10 to practice. You are correct, deleting plugin code returns a critical error. The "Space X-Chimp", 'My Custom Functions" plugin is the safer option.

Comment: I would argue on this point. It is possible to rewrite require_once without errors and not manually. But this plugin does not require such an approach, since the plugin contains many filters for rewriting included files via require_once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
add_filter( 'learn-press/admin-course-tabs', 'mb_remover', 10, 1 );
function mb_remover($default_tabs) {
  $default_tabs['payment'] = [];
  return $default_tabs;
}
```

Plugin has a lot of filters and you can manage almost all content.
It will remove this section: [image]

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I have implemented the change and I have practiced with the same logic on a number of plugin and Wordpress default features, removing certain columns and Screen Options. Thank you again.

Comment: @yurakosyak in the opposite side would you give me a hint about how to add another option inside the pricing tab ?